# Duplicated key in meteor collection with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, uuid, meteor

I'm currently develop an meteor app and sometimes my server goes down with this error:

Exception while invoking method '/songs/insert' MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: megan.songs.$*id*  dup key: { : "399dc507-b1fe-4e0f-a2c4-fa3dabd2bdf5" }

The insert method is called in this way:

Songs.insert({name: vid, score: weight, title:title, listkey:Session.get('listkey')});

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance,

Topicus

Answer (score 2):

Which key is getting duplicated? The ObjectId (_id) field can't be duplicating. Is it the listkey field? Probably you have a unique index set on the listkey field and somehow your Session.get() is returning an existing key and that's why your insert is failing..Can you execute:

```
db.Songs.find({listkey:"399dc507-b1fe-4e0f-a2c4-fa3dabd2bdf5"});
```

and check if there are mutiple documents returned?

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is your solution but... you can get this issue if you're using SimpleSchema and you've specified 'unique' or 'index' on the field. You'll need to .drop() even if you've modified the SimpleSchema object to remove the constraint.